Using Environment variable in package.json through dotenv-cli
In my react project want to start production environment through .env config port.
This is my .env file:
PORT                = 3001
APP_BE_IP           = 127.0.0.1
APP_BE_PORT         = 3333
REACT_APP_API_KEY   = 'http://${APP_BE_IP}:${APP_BE_PORT}/'
API_TIMEOUT_MS      = 10000

I have add dotenv-cli in package.json
{
  ... ... ...
  ... ... ...
  "scripts": {
    "envport": "dotenv -p PORT",
    "start:prod1": "serve -s build -l ${dotenv -p PORT}", // Need to Configure with env.PORT
    "start:prod":  "serve -s build 3001",
    "build:prod": "react-scripts build",
    "prod": "npm run build:prod && npm run start:prod"
    ... ... ...
  }
  "dependencies": {
    ... ... ...
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    ... ... ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv-cli": "^7.4.2",
    ... ... ...
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  ... ... ...
}

when run npm run envport it's returning correct env.PORT value (3001).
But how to use that in npm run start:prod script ?

Using: dotenv-cli
After lots of research found solution EOD.
And My final script is :
{
  ... ... ...
  ... ... ...
  "scripts": {
    "start:prod":  "dotenv -e .env serve -s build -l $PORT",
    "build:prod": "react-scripts build",
    "prod": "npm run build:prod && npm run start:prod"
    ... ... ...
  }
  ... ... ...
  ... ... ...
}

